# Mongoose - Unable to fetch data in find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am sending an API request which contains space.  I remove the space with `decodeURIComponent` but still I am getting `[]` in response. Here is my code:

```
    router.get('/products/searchproduct/:name', (req, res, next) => {

    var request = decodeURIComponent(req.params.name)
    console.log('------------------------------------');
    console.log(request);
    console.log('------------------------------------');
    Product.find({
        'category.category_name': decodeURIComponent(req.params.name)
    }, function (err, document) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).send("There was a problem getting the category based record .");
        console.log('------------------------------------');
        console.log(decodeURIComponent(req.params.name));
        console.log('------------------------------------');
        res.status(200).send(document);

    })
});
```

[image]

**product schema**

```
    //this file contain content scheme

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//function to call monggose schema
const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    product_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    product_price: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_btc: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_mode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_date: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_hasrate: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_powerConsumption: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_efficiency: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_voltage: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_frequency: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_shipment: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_warranty: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    product_contact: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
})

const Product = module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Comment: are you getting query params

Comment: console.log(decodeURIComponent(req.params.name)); what is the output of this

Comment: Yea I get the perfect params which is actually 'Gpu Miners' with a space, but god knows why this find is not working

Comment: does the db contains those requested items?

Comment: yea man, there are two items let me take a screen shot

Comment: At a quick bet, your collection is called `"product"` isn't it? Please don't past screen shots. Use "text".

Comment: can u share the schema code

Comment: check the screen shot and schema

Comment: Product.find({
        'category.category_name': decodeURIComponent(req.params.name)
    } check this query

Comment: Please switch the view tab to "text" in Robo 3T and take a close look at that field. Does the value in the database itself have trailing spaces or similar.

Comment: Huh finally , it was the space coming at the end of 'GPU MINERS' during posting data. Thanks man

Comment: So the lesson to learn is "step away from the uninformative graphical view". Very easy to spot these things in plain text. And I don't have to squint at pictures when you do. See the clear code in your post? See how unclear a screenshot is.

Comment: Sorry @Neil i am not that professional. Looking fwd to learn from you in the  very future